# How do I run Eclipse with the -clear flag after a manual install?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation

How do I run Eclipse with the -clear flag in Windows? (I'm trying to do it for installing a plugin manually.) I'm not quite sure what that means either, so I'm going to let you answer that one. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is `-clean` (clean, not clear).

You can run Eclipse from the command prompt and specify the option on the command line:

```
eclipse -clean
```

Or you can edit the existing `eclipse.ini` file in the install directory and add a new line containing `-clean` (at the top not the bottom). Remove the line again after you have started Eclipse as it will slow down the Eclipse startup.